# Adding page support caused errors - Pageable pageable - spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have Repository like this:

```
public interface IDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, String>{
}
```

after I adding paging support like this:

```
public interface IDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, String>{    
    Page<Domain> getDomains(String projectId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I have error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property get found for type class org.krams.tutorial.domain.nosql.Domain
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.<init>(Property.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.<init> ...
```

the versions in my pom.xml are:

```
<!-- Versions -->
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.data.mongo.version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.data.mongo.version>
        <spring.amqp.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
        <org.cloudfoundry-version>0.8.0</org.cloudfoundry-version>
        <jackson-mapper>1.9.10</jackson-mapper>
    </properties>
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, get it ! 
The reason of the error is :
If you want to use with Pageable in MongoRepository,
Domain object need to have member Domains, so you can add function like

```
public Page<Domain> findByDomains(String domains, Pageable pageable);
```